Next.js + RTK Query: How do I integrate server side rendering with RTK data fetching?
I want to render a static listing with cached HTML on initial page load using data that was fetched server side.
I do NOT want to display a loading indicator on initial page load. I want to display cached HTML data that was fetched on the server, not in browser.
HOWEVER I also want RTK Query to be able to handle updates to the list data if the list data is updated.
At the moment, I have this code:
app/discussions/page.tsx
import { DiscussionList } from '../components/DiscussionList'

export default async function DiscussionListPage() {
    return <DiscussionList />
}


app/components/DiscussionList.tsx
export function DiscussionList() {
    const { data, isFetching } = useFetchDiscussionsQuery()

    if (isFetching) {
        return <p>Loading...</p>
    }

    return (
        <ul>
            {data?.map((item) => (
                <li key={item.discussionId}>
                    <h2>{item.title}</h2>
                    <p>{item.body}</p>
                </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
    )
}

This displays a loading indicator in the static HTML at the moment, not prefetched data.
I need to change it so it renders list items on page load instead of the loading indicator.

This was the solution I came up with:
app/discussions/page.tsx
'use server'

export default async function DiscussionListPage() {
    // Next.js will cache the result of this server-side fetch request
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/discussions', {
        // set up for on-demand server cache invalidation
        next: { tags: ['discussions'] },
    })
    const data = await response.json()

    // Feed the server fetched data into DiscussionList as a prop
    return <DiscussionList ssrData={data} />
}

app/components/DiscussionList.tsx
'use client'

interface DiscussionListProps {
    ssrData: Array<Discussion> | undefined
}

export function DiscussionList({ ssrData }: DiscussionListProps) {
    const { data, isFetching } = useFetchDiscussionsQuery()

    // While RTK Query is being fetched, use the SSR discussions data
    const finalData = data || ssrData || []

    return (
        <ul>
            // Indicating to the user that new data is being fetched
            // so the list might change
            {isFetching && <li>Updating list...</li>}
            {finalData.map((item) => (
                <li key={item.discussionId}>
                    <h2>{item.title}</h2>
                    <p>{item.body}</p>
                </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
    )
}

Use on-demand revalidation to invalidate the cache when appropriate.
'use server'
 
import { revalidateTag } from 'next/cache'
 
export default async function action() {
  revalidateTag('collection')
}

